# cookies aren't being stored after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am storing cookies from form values using the below code. I can see that the cookies have been stored when I look under Application > Cookies in developer tools. When you press submit on this form, it takes you to the start of a survey. The pages of the survey are within the same file path of the form page. After the first page of the survey loads, I check in developer tools and the cookies aren't there. This only happens randomly, but I've found that it happens much more often on Macbooks using Chrome. I am on a pc using chrome and it's never happened to me.

```
// Script to set cookies
      function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
          document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      }
    // Script to get cookies
      function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
      }

    //Check for enabled cookies
    function areCookiesEnabled() {
      document.cookie = "__verify=1";
      var supportsCookies = document.cookie.length >= 1 &&
                            document.cookie.indexOf("__verify=1") !== -1;
      var thePast = new Date(1976, 8, 16);
      document.cookie = "__verify=1;expires=" + thePast.toUTCString();
      return supportsCookies;
    }

    //Set cookies on form submission
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#fn-2" ).change(function() {
          setCookie("firstName", this.value, 30; path=appfire.com/club);
        });
        $( "#ln-2" ).change(function() {
          setCookie("lastName", this.value, 30);
        });
        $( "#eml-2" ).change(function() {
          setCookie("email", this.value, 30);
        });
      });
      $("#wf-form-club_profile_creator").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (areCookiesEnabled() ) {
          console.log('Cookies are enabled.');
          window.location.replace("http://www.appfire.com/club/quiz/q1");
        } else {
         console.log('Cookies are disabled');
         alert('Cookies appear to be disabled in your browser. To create your A List club profile, please enable cookies and try again. Thanks!');
         window.location.replace("http://www.appfire.com/club");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Where are you requesting if the cookie exists or not??

Comment: From what I am reading. The user makes a change to a Input field, then the page submits, and replaces the url? But, your calling a submit? Why? What are you trying to accomplish. The code doesnt make sense.

Comment: I have the inputs setting cookies on change so that I can see that cookies are being set before the user hits the submit button. This is a generic form that is generated from a CMS that I have to overwrite the submit function. The purpose of this form is to collect user information, store it, then direct the user to a survey. At the end of the survey, the back end will collect the first name, last name, email address and values of answers chosen from the survey. The answers are being stored in session storage, however session storage wouldn't work for the user info after submitting.